# Generic method with dynamic T

Tags: c#, generics

I'm making a small example to check the type of parameter is valid or not.

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
}

class C
{
}

class D
{
    public void SomeMethod<T>(T t) where T : class
    {
        if (t is A)
        {
            A a = t as A;
        }
        else if (t is B)
        {
            B b = t as B;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I can call:

```
A a = new A();
SomeMethod<A>(a);

B b = new B();
SomeMethod<B>(b);
```

Now, I want to prevent to passing class `C` to `SomeMethod`. What I want to achieve:

```
C c = new C();
SomeMethod<C>(c); // error
```

To do that, I've tried:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T t) where T : A
{
    // accept only class A
}
```

or

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T t) where T : B
{
    // accept only class B
}
```

My question is: how to declare `SomeMethod` with `T` can be `A` or `B` at the same time? Just like:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T t) where T : A, B
{
    // accept class A and class B
}
```

Comment: No you can't do this as it defeats the point in using generics in the first place. If you have a fixed number of cases you support, define an overload for each case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Lee has mentioned, this defeats the purpose of generics. To ahieve what you're describing just write overloads for each case

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C { }

class D
{
    public void SomeMethod(A a)
    {
        //Do stuff with a
    }
    public void SomeMethod(B b)
    {
        //Do stuff with b
    }
}
```

If you wanted to have a run-time error you could do something like this:

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C { }    

class D
{
    public void SomeMethod<T>(T t) where T : class
    {
        if (t is A)
        {
            A a = t as A;
        }
        else if (t is B)
        {
            B b = t as B;
        }
        else //if (t is C)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Though this is a poor solution. The overload solution is still cleaner and will give a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like really bad practice but I think you could do

```
class D
{
    public void SomeMethod<T>(T t) where T : class
    {
        if (t is A)
            A a = t as A;
        else if (t is B)
            B b = t as B;
        else
            throw new Exception("Wrong class type.");
    }
}
```

This way you can use the method with only classes `A` and `B`, and it will throw an error for class `C` - and others.

Comment: I got -1 and the top answer has copied mine in a edit.